# Как парсить аргументы командной строки?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, консоль

Пишу консольное приложение которое должно принимать более 5 параметров. При этом есть обязательные параметры есть не обязательные, одни параметры должны работать только с другими и т.д.. Я уже погряз в различных if..else if..else. Как облегчить себе жизнь? Есть ли рекомендации и стандартные приёмы по работе с аргументами командной строки?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Если параметров много, лучше всего вынести их разбор в отдельный класс или набор классов. Когда `if`/`else` образуют сложную структуру, можно использовать «повышенную декларативность» C# и описывать структуру команд, например, так:

```
var commandLinePattern = Command.WithName('add')
                                .HasOption('-fileName')

                       | Command.WithName('help')
                                .HasParameter("CommandName");
```

Конечно, это потребует определённой изобретательности при проектировании, так что ниже изложу подробнее.

Следующим шагом мы опишем наши команды:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Run();
}

public HelpCommand : ICommand
{
    public string CommandName { get; set; }

    public bool Verbose { get; set; }

    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public void Run()
    {
        if (CommandName == "add")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Help on the ADD command");
        }
        . . .
    }
}
```

Шаблон командной строке (переменная `commandLinePattern` в первом примере) можно применить к конкретной строке параметров, чтобы построить экземпляр конкретного класса команды, и заполнить его свойства, использую рефлексию:

```
var command = commandLinePattern.Parse(args);
command.Run();
```

**UPDATE**

Итого, получается приблизительно такой код:

```
static class Program
{
    private static readonly СommandLinePattern commandLinePattern = Command.WithName('add')
                                                        .HasOption('-fileName')
                                                        .HasOption('-move')

                                               | Command.WithName('help')
                                                        .Parameter("CommandName");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var command = commandLinePattern.Parse(args);
        command.Run();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE «для новичка»**

Немного о том, как реализовать всю эту красоту. Наше чудо по внешнему виду и внутреннему устройству очень напоминает регулярные выражения: сначала мы описываем некий *шаблон* аргументов командной строки, и затем *применяем* его к реальным аргументам. Результатом такого *применения* будет объект, который можно будет *выполнить*. Назовём его **командой**.

Название **команда** возникло не просто так — это один из паттернов проектирования, описанный в классическом труде банды четырёх.

Я не знаю, какие командные строки вам приходится разбирать, поэтому сделаю несколько предположений:

1. Программа может выполнить за один запуск одну и только одну команду. Команда идёт первой в командной строке. Команда не требует префиксов, таких как дефис или косая черта.
2. За командой могут следовать один или несколько параметров. Параметры могут быть именованными и безымянными. Именованные параметры имеют префикс, например, дефис. Именованные параметры могут иметь значение, в этом случае оно отделяется от имени двоеточием.

Приблизительно такие правила используются в большом количестве утилит, например, в архиваторах `pkzip`, `arj` и `rar`; в утилитах контроля версий `git` и `hg` — то есть этих двух правил действительно хватает для широкого спектра задач.

```
arj add archive *.c -m0
```

`arj` — это имя программы, `add` — команда, `archive` (имя архива) и `*.c` (что архивировать) — безымянные параметры; `-m` — именованный параметр (опция), `0` — значение параметра.

*В arj значение параметра не требуется отделять символом : или =. Мы пойдём другим путём, исключительно для из-за того, что пример демонстрационный.*

Такой шаблон параметра командной строки может быть описан простым классом:

```
public class CommandLinePattern
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> Parameters { get; set; }

    public List<string> Options { get; set; }
}
```

Например, команда **help** может иметь такой шаблон

```
program Help CommandName [-Verbose] [-PageSize:num]
```

Которому соответствует экземпляр класса `CommandLinePattern`:

```
var pattern = new CommandLinePattern
{
    Name = "Help",
    Parameters = new List<string> { "CommandName" },
    Options = new List<string> { "Verbose", "PageSize" },
};
```

Нам нужно решить две задачи: построить такой шаблон, и применить его. В коде выше мы воспользовались статическим классом `Command` для того, чтобы начать конструировать шаблон:

```
public static class Command
{
    public static CommandLinePattern WithName(string name)
    {
        return new CommandLinePattern
        {
            Name = name,
            Parameters = new List<string>(),
            Options = new List<string>(),
        };
    }
}
```

Остальные методы конструирования разместим непосредственно в классе `CommandLinePattern`:

```
public CommandLinePattern HasOption(string name)
{
    Options.Add(name);

    return this;
}

public CommandLinePattern HasParameter(string name)
{
    Parameters.Add(name);

    return this;
}
```

Благодаря конструкции `return this;` мы можем строить объект последовательно, увязывая методы в цепочку:

```
var pattern = Command.WithName("Help")
                     .HasParameter("CommandName")
                     .HasOption("Verbose")
                     .HasOption("PageSize");
```

Таким образом мы описываем шаблоны команды. Теперь решим вторую задачу — разбор командной строки и создание объекта-команды.

В классе `CommandLinePattern` реализуем метод `TryParse`, который будет пробовать разобрать командную строку и в случае успеха создавать объект, реализующий такой интерфейс `ICommand`:

```
public virtual bool TryParse(string[] args, out ICommand result)
{
    result = null;
    // Конечно, наш шаблон не может соответствовать пустой командной строке.
    if (args.Length == 0)
        return false;

    // И он не может соответствовать какой-то другой команде.
    if (args[0] != Name)
        return false;

    var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var nextParameterIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        if (args[i].StartsWith("-"))
        {
            var parameterWithoutHyphen = args[i].Substring(1);
            var nameValue = parameterWithoutHyphen.Split(':');
            if (nameValue.Length == 1)
                properties.Add(nameValue[0], null);
            else
                properties.Add(nameValue[0], nameValue[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            var name = Parameters[nextParameterIndex++];

            var value = args[i];
            properties.Add(name, value);
        }
    }

    // Для команды с именем Help мы найдём класс HelpCommand:
    var className = Name + "Command";
    var type = Type.GetType(className);
    // И создадим его экземпляр:
    result = (ICommand)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // Теперь значения всех параметров запишем в свойства
    // только что созданного экземпляра:
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var name = property.Key;
        var value = property.Value;

        type.GetProperty(name)
            .SetValue(result, value);
    }

    return true;
}

public virtual ICommand Parse(string[] args)
{
    ICommand result;
    if (TryParse(args, out result))
        return result;

    throw new FormatException();
}
```

Имейте в виду, что такая запись значений будет работать только со строковыми свойствами — в реальной программе вам потребуется конвертировать строковые значения в типы свойств.

Теперь у нас уже всё готово. Мы можем написать наш разбор параметров, но «для красоты» сделаем ещё один финальный штрих.

Создадим класс, который позволит объединить два шаблона и проверять сначала левый, а затем правый:

```
public class OrCommandLinePattern : CommandLinePattern
{
    private readonly CommandLinePattern left;
    private readonly CommandLinePattern right;

    public OrCommandLinePattern(CommandLinePattern left, CommandLinePattern right)
    {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public override bool TryParse(string[] args, out ICommand result)
    {
        if (left.TryParse(args, out result))
            return true;

        return right.TryParse(args, out result);
    }
}
```

В базовый класс добавим реализацию оператора **ИЛИ**:

```
public static CommandLinePattern operator |(CommandLinePattern left, CommandLinePattern right)
{
    return new OrCommandLinePattern(left, right);
}
```

Теперь мы можем объединить несколько паттернов с помощью вертикальной черты:

```
var commandLinePattern = Command.WithName('add')
                                .HasOption('-fileName')

                       | Command.WithName('help')
                                .HasParameter("CommandName");
```

И в конце запускаем парсинг с помощью вызова одного единственного метода:

```
var command = commandLinePattern.Parse(args);
```

Результатом работы парсера будет экземпляр класса, реализующего интерфейс `ICommand` с заполненными свойствами. Нам остаётся только запустить его:

```
command.Run();
```

**UPDATE — готовая реализация (декабрь 2019)**

В конце концов написал готовый код и выложил его в виде NuGet-проекта.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Binateq.CommandLine/ — пакет

https://github.com/binateq/command-line-parser — исходный код на GitHub

Comment: Чую это близко к тому, что мне нужно. А как это применять? Реальный работающий пример можно?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin Не очень понятен вопрос. Дополнил ответ тем, как применять, но это просто тот же код, что и выше, сведённый в одном методе `Main`.

Comment: Для новичка лишние примеры и пояснения будут не лишними. Спасибо!

Comment: @MikhailDanshin Написал подробный ответ со всеми, как я надеюсь, техническими деталями. Если что-то ещё непонятно, задавайте вопросы.

Comment: Вы дали потрясающий ответ. Если бы в результате вы всё собрали бы в один неразрывный листинг, то это было бы замечательнейшим пособием для любого уровня. Но не смею просить Вас об этом. Тем не менее у меня есть пара уточнений. Правильно я понял, что в строке **public HelpCommand : ICommand** пропущено слово class и ее следует писать как **public class HelpCommand : ICommand**? Второй вопрос на строчку **result = (ICommand)Activator.CreateClass(type);** компилятор ругается **'Activator' does not contain a definition for 'CreateClass'**. Следует использовать CreateInstance?

Comment: В строке **private static readonly commandLinePatterm** опечатка в последней букве.

Comment: Последняя ошибка компилятора **'CommandLinePattern.Parameters' cannot be used like a method.** Пока не могу понять что с этим делать.

Comment: Это какая-то опечатка — похоже на круглые скобки вместо квадратных.

Comment: если круглые скобки в этой строке заменить на квадратные, то возникает вот такая ошибка **cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'**

Comment: @MikhailDanshin Сделал простой проект, он компилируется и работает со свойствами типа `int`, `string`, `bool`. Выложил на [github](https://github.com/markshevchenko/command-line-parser), берите, и доводите так, как Вам нужно. Обработки ошибок там нет, придётся написать самому.

Comment: Марк, добрый день. Вы убрали проект с GitHub? Не могу его найти.

Comment: @MarkНе могли бы вы пояснить, что происходит здесь?
`var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>(); var nextParameterIndex = 0; for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++) { if (args[i].StartsWith("-")) { var parameterWithoutHyphen = args[i].Substring(1); var nameValue = parameterWithoutHyphen.Split(':'); if (nameValue.Lenth == 1) properties.Add(nameValue[0], null); else properties.Add(nameValue[0], nameValue[1]); } else { var name = Parameters[nextParameterIndex]; nextParameterIndex++; var value = args[i]; properties.Add(name, value);}}`

Comment: @Leviathan_ZC, пробегаемся по всем параметрам командной строки. Если они имеют вид **-name** или **-name:value**, заносим их в словарь `properties`. Чуть позже присвоим значения свойствам класса `Command`. Если это параметры, которые не начинаются с дефиса, мы их заносим в список `Parameters`.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko спасибо большое)

Answer (score 3):

[Отличный парсер аргументов командной строки](https://github.com/nessos/Argu). Единственный минус - придётся написать небольшую прослойку на F# (~20-30 строк). Действительно небольшую - можно посмотреть [туториал](http://nessos.github.io/Argu/tutorial.html).

Comment: Не понимаю человека, который заминусил 2 ответа на вопрос.